# What allows me to `require` a module or library in react js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I follow some tutorial to build some react app.

and I found the js file include some module like below.

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var React = require('React');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var url = require('url');
var moment = require('moment');

var NewsItem = React.createClass({
    .........code.......
```

I thought only in node.js app can require module like that.
or all js app can do like this?

Can any one explain to me?

Below is my package.son file..

```
{
  "name": "hn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "reactify"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^11.2.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Browserify is what makes this possible.

Comment: Or more likely these days (especially in the React ecosystem) is webpack.

Answer (score 1):

React.js relies on node and npm as prerequisites, and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) allows you to require modules on the client side (in your browser).